# R - convert DFM to LSA then compute cosine similarity: Error inherits(x, "Matrix") is not TRUE

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda, lsa

I have a Document-Features-Matrix (DFM): 
I want to convert it into a LSA object and finally to compute cosine similarity between each documents.

this are the passages I followed

```
lsa_t2 <- convert(DFM_tfidf, to = "lsa" , omit_empty = TRUE)
t2_lsa_tfidf_cos_sim = sim2(x = lsa_t2, method = "cosine", norm = "l2")
```

but I get this error:

> Error in sim2(x = lsa_t2, method = "cosine", norm = "l2") :
>   inherits(x, "matrix") || inherits(x, "Matrix") is not TRUE

to give more context this is what las_t2 looks like

[image: How lsa_t2 looks like]

any of the documents contain text (I check it already) and I filtered outdocuments without text before I cleated the dfm.

Any idea of what happened?

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with one of the datasets available in quanteda. Also mention where the function `sim2` comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you receive basically means that the function `sim2` does not work with the `lsa` object. However, I'm not really sure if I understand the question. Why do you want to convert the `dfm` to `lsa` textmatrix format in the first place?

If you want to calculate cosine similarity between texts, you can do this directly in `quenteda`

```
library(quanteda)

texts <- c(d1 = "Shipment of gold damaged in a fire",
           d2 = "Delivery of silver arrived in a silver truck",
           d3 = "Shipment of gold arrived in a truck" )

texts_dfm <- dfm(texts)

textstat_simil(texts_dfm, 
               margin = "documents",
               method = "cosine")
#> textstat_simil object; method = "cosine"
#>       d1    d2    d3
#> d1 1.000 0.359 0.714
#> d2 0.359 1.000 0.598
#> d3 0.714 0.598 1.000
```

If you want to use `sim2` from `text2vec`, you can do so using the same object without converting it first:

```
library(text2vec)
sim2(x = texts_dfm, method = "cosine", norm = "l2")
#> 3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"
#>           d1        d2        d3
#> d1 1.0000000 0.3585686 0.7142857
#> d2 0.3585686 1.0000000 0.5976143
#> d3 0.7142857 0.5976143 1.0000000
```

As you can see, the results are the same.

#### Update

As by the comments, I now understand that you want to apply a transformation of your data via Latent semantic analysis. You can follow the tutorial linked below and plug in the dfm instead of the dtm that is used in the tutorial:

```
texts_dfm_tfidf <- dfm_tfidf(texts_dfm)


library(text2vec)
lsa = LSA$new(n_topics = 2)
dtm_tfidf_lsa = fit_transform(texts_dfm_tfidf, lsa) # I get a warning here, probably due to the size of the toy dfm
d1_d2_tfidf_cos_sim = sim2(x = dtm_tfidf_lsa, method = "cosine", norm = "l2")
d1_d2_tfidf_cos_sim
#>              d1           d2        d3           d4
#> d1  1.000000000 -0.002533794 0.5452992  0.999996189
#> d2 -0.002533794  1.000000000 0.8368571 -0.005294431
#> d3  0.545299245  0.836857086 1.0000000  0.542983071
#> d4  0.999996189 -0.005294431 0.5429831  1.000000000
```

Note that these results differ from run to run unless you use `set.seed()`.

Or if you want to do everything in `quanteda`:

```
texts_lsa <- textmodel_lsa(texts_dfm_tfidf, 2)

textstat_simil(as.dfm(texts_lsa$docs), 
               margin = "documents",
               method = "cosine")
#> textstat_simil object; method = "cosine"
#>          d1       d2    d3       d4
#> d1  1.00000 -0.00684 0.648  1.00000
#> d2 -0.00684  1.00000 0.757 -0.00894
#> d3  0.64799  0.75720 1.000  0.64638
#> d4  1.00000 -0.00894 0.646  1.00000
```

Comment: the thing is that I wanted to try with a LSA representation of my documents before applying cosine similarity to compare the results I obtained using cosine similarity on my dim (with tf-idf)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the `textmatrix` object you get using `convert(DFM_tfidf, to = "lsa")` is just a different format than `dfm`. Both are basically document-term matrices that have the content and dimensions and are just technically different. The transformation therefore seems pointless to me. Do you maybe have a different representation of your data in mind?

Comment: http://text2vec.org/similarity.html#practical_examples I was following this link example using my own data ( I am referring to the paragraph "Cosine similarity with LSA"). the author suggests tf-idf might not be good enough and tries using lsa